# How to use JCo connection without creating *.JcoDestination file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, sap-erp, jco, bapi

I'm trying to connect to SAP ECC 6.0 using JCo. I'm following [this](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi711/helpdata/en/48/5fb9f9b523501ee10000000a421937/content.htm) tutorial. However, there is a Note saying:

```
For this example the destination configuration is stored in a file that is called by the program. In practice you should avoid this for security reasons.
```

And that is reasonable and understood. But, there is no explenation how to set up secure destination provider. 
I found solution in this [thread](https://scn.sap.com/thread/1014595) that created custom implementation of `DestinationDataProvider` and that works on my local machine. But when I deploy it on Portal I get an error saying that there is already registered `DestinationDataProvider`. 
So my question is:
**How to store destination data in SAP Java EE application?**

Here is my code to further clarify what I'm trying to do.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws JCoException {
        CustomDestinationProviderMap provider = new CustomDestinationProviderMap();
        com.sap.conn.jco.ext.Environment.registerDestinationDataProvider(provider);

        Properties connectProperties = new Properties();
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_ASHOST, "host.sap.my.domain.com");
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_SYSNR, "00");
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_CLIENT, "100");
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_USER, "user");
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_PASSWD, "password");
        connectProperties.setProperty(DestinationDataProvider.JCO_LANG, "en");

        provider.addDestination(DESTINATION_NAME1, connectProperties);
        connect();
    }

    public static void connect() throws JCoException {
        String FUNCTION_NAME = "BAPI_EMPLOYEE_GETDATA";
        JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(DESTINATION_NAME1);
        JCoContext.begin(destination);

        JCoFunction function = destination.getRepository().getFunction(FUNCTION_NAME);
        if (function == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(FUNCTION_NAME + " not found in SAP.");
        }

        //function.getImportParameterList().setValue("EMPLOYEE_ID", "48");
        function.getImportParameterList().setValue("FSTNAME_M", "ANAKIN");
        function.getImportParameterList().setValue("LASTNAME_M", "SKYWALKER");

        try {
            function.execute(destination);
        } catch (AbapException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return;
        }

        JCoTable table = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("PERSONAL_DATA");
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getNumRows(); i++) {
            table.setRow(i);
            System.out.println(table.getString("PERNO") + '\t' + table.getString("FIRSTNAME") + '\t' + table.getString("LAST_NAME")
            +'\t' + table.getString("BIRTHDATE")+'\t' + table.getString("GENDER"));
        }

        JCoContext.end(destination);
    }
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521272/building-jcoserver-without-properties-file?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I got this up and going and thought I'd share my research. 
You need to add your own destination in Portal. To achieve that you need to go to NetWeaver Administrator, located at: `host:port/nwa`. So it'll be something like `sapportal.your.domain.com:50000/nwa`.

Then you go to `Configuration`-> `Infrastructure`-> `Destinations` and add your destination there. You can leave empty most of the fields like Message Server. The important part is Destination name as it is how you will retrieve it and destination type which should be set to RFC Destination in my case. Try pinging your newly created destination to check if its up and going.

Finally you should be able to get destination by simply calling: `JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(DESTINATION_NAME);` as it is added to your Portal environment and managed from there.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the CustomDestinationDataProvider in the JCo examples of the Jco connector download. The important parts are:

```
static class MyDestinationDataProvider implements DestinationDataProvider
...
com.sap.conn.jco.ext.Environment.registerDestinationDataProvider(new MyDestinationDataProvider());
```

Then you can simply do:

```
instance = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(DESTINATION_NAME);
```

Btw. you may also want to check out http://hibersap.org/ as they provide nice ways to store the config as well.